# undefined method `role?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am trying to use CanCan on my rails application. I followed the same tutorial that I used previously on my other project and got this working. My following set up is as followed:

It seems that when I try to access my application I am given

```
undefined method `role?' for nil:NilClass
```

which points to the following line of my `application/layout.html.erb`

```
  <% if @user.role? :administrator %>
```

Comment: Are you creating `@user` in your application controller?

Comment: No I do not create a `@user in my application controller. I have included my application controller into the question

Comment: The problem is that @user is not defined. You need to declare this somewhere. Change your if statement in application/layout.rb to `<% if @user && @user.role? :administration %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `@user` is not always defined in every controller action, but your layout is being rendered on every controller action, so `@user` will sometimes be null. To fix this, just check that @user is defined in your if statement like this:

```
<% if @user && @user.role?(:administrator) %>
```

Comment: I got the following error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4752437 That didn't seem to work. I even tried what you suggested and do `<% if @user && @user.current_user.role? :administrator %>` and this also did not work

Comment: Can you try `<% if @user && @user.role?(:administrator) %>`? You might need to use parenthesis for the argument.

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the @user method seems to be nil. and As per the cancan documentation it expects a [current_user](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#getting-started) method to be exist,

and also I can see you have commented out the

[before_filter :authenticate_user!](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#getting-started), make it enable so that it will create the current user,

and also enable the `load_and_authorize_resource`, for cancan to work correctly.

Comment: Okay I just found that I was given a different error - `uninitialized constant Session` which points to `NameError in Devise::SessionsController#new` It also turns out that you shouldn't use `load_and_authorize_resource` inside the application controller. As Ryan Bates suggest on his following CanCan Issue #138 - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/138. So what I have done is un-commented the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` but left the `load_and_authorize_` commented out